# parameter passing issue

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a parameter passing problem.

I have 2 forms. Form A which is the main form and Form B which is opened from Form A.

In Form A I have a List of objects of a certain type. Form B's job is to create a new object for Form A to add to the said List.
So when Form B creates an object from user inputed data, I need it to pass the object to Form A and then it closes. This is where my question is, what logic do I use to pass the created object to the parent Form?

Pseudocode example:

Class Form A:
{
Variable declaration
List a;
Form B;

Action: Button pressed; Show Form B

}

Class Form B:

{
Variables: textField 1, textField 2;

Action: Submit button pressed; Create new Obj with values entered in textFields
}

When the new object is created in Form B, Form B will close, and I want the object to be added to the list in Form A.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code; it would help us see what you're passing between what clearer.

Comment: its not about the code, its the logic. But i understand it might be abit ambiguous so I have put a pseudocode example to ilustrate it in the original post.

Comment: Not seeing the pseudocode example yet.

Comment: Sorry, was just adding it. It should be up now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how complex your application is. In an simply application I would pass a reference of Form A to Form B. When Form B closes it can call a method of Form A to pass the created object and refresh itself.

Comment: Thank you. I shall give that a try.